# Carriage return lost while reading remote file

Tags: python

I'm reading a remote file which contains a list of data like these:

```
HTTP threads 200
HornetQ Server threads 100
HornetQ Client threads 16
Default threads 22
OOB threads 20
```

I'm using the following python code to read the file remotely:

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="myhost"

COMMAND="cat /space/monitor/monitor.log"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.read().splitlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

The output of the code shows the list of lines without the carriage return:

```
'Thu Jul 2 13:25:01 CEST 2015', 'HTTP threads 200', 'HornetQ Server threads 100', 'HornetQ Client threads 14', 'Default threads 22', 'OOB threads 20', 'Remoting threads 12', 'Thu Jul 2 13:30:01 CEST 2015', 'HTTP threads 200', 'HornetQ Server threads 100', 'HornetQ Client threads 17', 'Default threads 22', 'OOB threads 20', 'Remoting threads 12', 'Thu Jul 2 13:35:01 CEST 2015', 'HTTP threads 200', 'HornetQ Server threads 100', 'HornetQ Client threads 13', 'Default threads 22', 'OOB threads 20', 'Remoting threads 12', 'Thu Jul 2 13:40:01 CEST 2015', 'HTTP threads 200', 'HornetQ Server threads 100', 'HornetQ Client threads 11', 'Default threads 22', 'OOB threads 20', 'Remoting threads 12',
```

Update:
in my first attempt I have used:

```
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
```

However this produced "\n" in replacement of carriage returns:

```
 20\n', 'Remoting threads 12\n', 'Thu Jul 2 13:55:01 CEST 2015\n', 'HTTP threads 200\n', 'HornetQ Server threads 100\n', 'HornetQ Client threads 12\n', 'Default threads 22\n', 'OOB threads 20\n', 'Remoting threads 12\n', 'Thu Jul 2 14:00:01 CEST 2015\n', 'HTTP threads 200\n', 'HornetQ Server threads 100\n', 'HornetQ Client threads 12\n', 'Default threads 22\n', 'OOB threads 20\n', 'Remoting threads 12\n', 'Thu Jul 2 14:05:01 CEST 2015\n', 'HTTP threads 200\n', 'HornetQ Server threads 100\n', 'HornetQ Client threads 15\n', 'Default threads 22\n', 'OOB threads 20\n', 'Remoting threads 12\n']
```

I thought that split lines could fix it- however it merely replaced the "\n" with empty string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace commas with commas + carriage returns

```
result = str(result)
result = result.replace(",",",\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) is pretty clear:

> Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is given and true.

So try changing this:

```
result = ssh.stdout.read().splitlines()
```

to:

```
result = ssh.stdout.read().splitlines(True)
```

Of course, you can also join the lines back using `join()`:

```
lines = "\r".join(result)
```

The separator can be any thing, like carriage return.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to explain why I have used splitlines()

Answer (score 1):

Given your new problem description:

```
fullstring = ssh.stdout.read() ## will contain all the /bytes/ from stdout
split = fullstring.split('\r') ## will make substrings without the trailing `\r`
fullsplits = [s + '\r' for s in split] ## adding the \r back to the strings
```

Comment: Thanks, however by adding the new code still produced
['Thu Jul 2 14:24:17 CEST 2015\nHTTP threads 200\nHornetQ Server threads 100\nHornetQ Client threads 14\nDefault threads 22\nOOB threads 20\nRemoting threads 12\n']

Comment: Then, your original file didn't contain \r.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specifically tell python to get rid of that:

```
result = ssh.stdout.read().splitlines()
```

splits the things into lines, consuming the line breakig characters.
Don't do that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to explain why I have used splitlines()

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional parameter to splitlines - keepends. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

You have to call splitlines(True)